# Restructuring Dichotomy variable

Tags: r

I have variables with dichotomy responses say below

```
Brand1       Brand2
   1              1
   0              1
   1              1
   1              0
   0              1
```

And  I need to restructure to output for new variables like below

```
Var1        Var2
Brand1      Brand2  
Brand2      NA
Brand1      Brand2
Brand1      NA
Brand2      NA
```

For row 1 respondent only picked Brand1 and Brand2, and for row 2 respondent only pick Brand 2, then only the first variable we have value the second becomes None. My variables are more than 1000, I used 2 variables as example

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a smart answer for this but turns out I am not that smart ;-)

So here is one attempt

For every column first replace 1 with name of that column and 0 with NA using `lapply`

```
df[] <- lapply(names(df), function(x) ifelse(df[[x]] == 1, x, NA))
df

#  Brand1 Brand2
#1 Brand1 Brand2
#2   <NA> Brand2
#3 Brand1 Brand2
#4 Brand1   <NA>
#5   <NA> Brand2
```

If it is important to rearrange data by shifting `NA`s at the end of the row we can do it using `apply`

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df,1,function(x)  c(x[!is.na(x)],x[is.na(x)]))))

#      V1     V2
#1 Brand1 Brand2
#2 Brand2   <NA>
#3 Brand1 Brand2
#4 Brand1   <NA>
#5 Brand2   <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) names(df)[as.logical(x)][1:length(x)]))
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] "Brand1" "Brand2"
[2,] "Brand2" NA      
[3,] "Brand1" "Brand2"
[4,] "Brand1" NA      
[5,] "Brand2" NA
```

**Data**:

```
df <- structure(list(Brand1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Brand2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```